# Umbraco Member Tab - How to list the members

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco5, umbraco6

**Requirement**: I have a requirement such that, when a new user is registered in my application, his details should be stored in Umbraco Membership. I am Currently able to add the member to the umbraco site and i can see the added members under the Member Folder in the Member Tab. But the problem is if I added a person named "Vineeth", his details can only be viewed when I follow the path below 

**Member Tab - Member Folder - Letter "v" Folder.**

Similarly for each alphabets. Is there any way that I could see them all together. The reason I wanted to get the added members together is because my workflow is "The admin has to give approval for the registered users". So its not a good process for Admin to search under each alphabetic folder for the newly added members and approve them. So is there any way to list them together. I think one option there is adding the user control and populating the details in Grid View in that user-control and then display. Is there some other way that I could use for my requirement.

I checked with the way the search functionality is implemented in the Member section. But I am not sure how does this work. I identified the aspx page. but it has the code like below. So I am not sure what logic is written in the Search button functionality. Could you please advise me how can I do this. The path I found this is 

..\umbraco\Members\MemberSearch.ascx

Also I would like to know how is the list populated in the Search page.

Comment: Your best solution would be to create a user control that will list all the members that are not approved and register that control in the members dashboard. That way admin will be able to see those users in one place and you will keep the default implementation for listing the members.

Comment: Ok, Thanks!!.. but I found a solution at http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/blackpoint-member-admin. I think this is somewhat I wanted to have